# Coldfusion, Dropdown menu, Can a single option value contain multiple variables?

Tags: drop-down-menu, coldfusion

I am writing a CFM file to display a dropdown menu, in the dropdown options I want Var1 [Var2, Var3] to display for each line. I tried both concatenation and commas, tried a mix of brackets and quotes and cannot find the right combination. Using Oracle SQL developer. I am a student taking a database management class. I read through Adobe's site and cannot find an example like this. I also combed stack, but everything is PHP and javascript related. The result should have a dropdown, where each selection shows:  cus_code with corresponding [cus_fname, cus_lname] for each line. Below is the query that pulls the data needed and the dropdown menu. The place I am having trouble is in the output, where each line from the dropdown should have 3 variables. Every attempt I make causes an error.

```
 <!--Here is my query: grab customer code, last name, first name from customer table, join invoice table on customer code-->
    <CFQUERY NAME="INVOICESEARCH" DATASOURCE="ORCL">
    SELECT DISTINCT levine04.CUSTOMER6.CUS_CODE, CUS_LNAME, CUS_FNAME
    FROM levine04.CUSTOMER6, levine04.INVOICE6
    WHERE levine04.CUSTOMER6.CUS_CODE = levine04.INVOICE6.CUS_CODE;
    </CFQUERY>

    <!--Here is my dropdown:-->
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN="right">INV_NUMBER</TD>
        <TD> 
            <INPUT TYPE ="text" NAME="INV_NUMBER" SIZE="10" MAXLENGTH="10">
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN="right">CUS_CODE, [CUS_FNAME, CUS_LNAME]</TD>
        <TD>
            <SELECT NAME="CUS_CODE" SIZE=1>
            <OPTION SELECTED VALUE="ANY">ANY


        <CFOUTPUT QUERY="INVOICESEARCH">

<OPTION VALUE="#INVOICESEARCH.CUS_CODE#" + "#INVOICESEARCH.CUS_LNAME#" +"#INVOICESEARCH.CUS_FNAME#"> #CUS_CODE# + #CUSLNAME# + #CUSFNAME#
        </CFOUTPUT>
        </SELECT>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: Got it! But maybe this will help someone else...<OPTION VALUE="#INVOICESEARCH.CUS_CODE#"> #CUS_CODE#[#CUS_LNAME#, #CUS_FNAME#]

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Nothing to do with your question, but ... if you're learning try and [avoid using ANSI 89 style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) :)  Also, though it's technically optional, it's good style to include a closing `</option>` tag IMO

Comment: Might as well mention since you’re a student and learning this stuff, writing everything in all caps has been depreciated for a very long time. Also, writing CFML in tag mode these days is becoming less of a thing. Use cfscript syntax for modern CFML, though tag syntax is still nice sometimes. These are of course my opinions.

Comment: My comments: 1) As Ageax said, ANSI joins are a bad habit to get into. Use regular `JOIN` syntax instead. 2) Your query is called `InvoiceSearch` and you are joining an `INVOICE6` table, but you aren't selecting anything from the `INVOICE6` table.The query doesn't do anything with invoices, just customers. You should change the name to be more descriptive of what it does. Also, I'm guessing you ultimately intend to do something with the customer's invoices. This query will exclude any customer who doesn't have a valid invoice. Don't know if that's what you intend. 3) Use table aliases.

Comment: I would also note that the link Ageax pointed to is for Aaron Bertrand. He's mostly MS T-SQL, but much of what he writes is applicable to any flavor of SQL. He's definitely one of the best resources you can follow.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! But maybe this will help someone else..

```
<OPTION VALUE="#INVOICESEARCH.CUS_CODE#"> #CUS_CODE#[#CUS_LNAME#, #CUS_FNAME#]
```

Comment: YOU MIGHT WANT TO ENCODE THESE VARIABLES WHEN OUTPUTTING, SEE [EncodeForHTML](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforhtml.html).